# no python application found, check your startup logs for errors

Tags: docker, flask, uwsgi

My file structure looks like this:

```
nginx
`-- default.conf
mysql
client
server
|-- app
|   |-- db
|   |-- lib
|   |-- __init__.py
`-- app.ini
`-- dev.Dockerfile
`-- main.py
`-- requirements.txt
dev.yml
```

this is my 'app.ini' file:

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file: /app/main.py
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
socket = :5555
processes = 1
threads = 1
master = true
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
callable = app
die-on-term = true
```

my 'main.py' file:

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 5000, False)
```

my 'dev.Dockerfile' file:

```
FROM python:3.9.16


WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt


RUN  cd /app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


CMD ["uwsgi", "app.ini"]
```

my 'app.**init**.py' file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from datetime import timedelta
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from app.db import db, mm
from app.resourses import initialize_routes
from app.resourses.auth import AuthError
from app.error_handeler import handler
from app.lib import get_db_string
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask_cors import CORS
from app.db.models import get_user_by_id
from app.lib import set_default_companies

BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

if os.environ.get('ENV') == 'development':
    load_dotenv(f'{os.getcwd()}/.env.dev', override=True)
else:
    load_dotenv(f'{os.getcwd()}/.env', override=True)


def create_app():

    api = Flask(__name__)

    api.config['JWT_PRIVATE_KEY'] = os.environ.get("PRIVATE_KEY")
    api.config['JWT_PUBLIC_KEY'] = os.environ.get("PUB_KEY")
    api.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] = os.environ.get("JWT_SECRET")
    api.config["JWT_HEADER_NAME"] = "access_token"
    api.config["JWT_HEADER_TYPE"] = ""
    api.config["JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION"] = ["headers", "cookies", "json"]
    api.config["JWT_COOKIE_SECURE"] = os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'production'
    api.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True
    api.config["JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES"] = timedelta(minutes=1)
    api.config["JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES"] = timedelta(days=90)
    api.config['JWT_ACCESS_COOKIE_PATH'] = '/api/'
    api.config['JWT_REFRESH_COOKIE_PATH'] = '/token/refresh'
    api.config['JWT_ACCESS_COOKIE_NAME'] = 'access_token'
    api.config['JWT_REFRESH_COOKIE_NAME'] = 'refresh_token'
    api.config['JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT'] = False
    api.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
    api.config["PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS"] = True
    api.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = get_db_string()
    api.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
    api.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {
        'pool_size': 100,
    }
    api.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE'] = 100
    api.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE'] = 280
    api.secret_key = os.environ.get('FLASK_SECRET')

    db.init_app(api)
    mm.mm.init_app(api)
    with api.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        set_default_companies()

    handler(api)
    initialize_routes(api)
    CORS(api)
    api.config['TESTING'] = os.environ.get("TEST_MODE", default=False)

    @api.errorhandler(AuthError)
    def handle_auth_error(ex):
        response = jsonify(ex.error)
        response.status_code = ex.status_code
        return response
    return api


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_app().run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

my 'dev.yml' file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: ./dev.Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    networks:
      - nginx_network
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./client/build:/usr/share/nginx/html



  db:
    container_name: db
    build: ./mysql
    restart: always
    command: '--authentication_policy=mysql_native_password'
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "127.0.0.1", "--silent" ]
      interval: 3s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s

    networks:
      mysql_net:
        aliases:
            - db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data/data_volume:/var/lib/mysql

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: ./dev.Dockerfile
    container_name: server
    restart: always
    networks:
      mysql_net:
        aliases:
          - server
      nginx_network:
        aliases:
          - server
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./server/.env
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app


  #  frontend:
  #    build: /app/client
  #    container_name: client
  #    restart: always
  #    volumes:
  #      - /app/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html


  adminer:
    container_name: adminer
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    networks:
      mysql_net:
        aliases:
          - adminer
      nginx_network:
        aliases:
          - adminer
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"


volumes:
  data_volume:
    driver: local


networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge
  mysql_net:
    driver: bridge
```

my 'default.conf' file:

```
underscores_in_headers on;

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name localhost;

#     location /api {
#         proxy_pass_header http://server:5000;
#         proxy_pass http://server:5000;
#     }

    location /api {
        include uwsgi_params;
        add_header  Content-Type    application/json;
        uwsgi_pass server:5555;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
    }

    location /adminer {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix "/adminer";
        proxy_pass http://adminer:8080;
    }

   location ~* \.(?:css|js|json)$ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/;
    }

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

Whenever I start the server,
`docker-compose -f dev.yml up`
I get the following output:

```
.....                                                                                                                                                                                           

db              | 2022-12-15T22:37:45.439021Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
db              | 2022-12-15T22:37:45.439178Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.28'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
server  | --- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
server  | [pid: 7|app: -1|req: -1/1] 172.19.0.1 () {64 vars in 1258 bytes} [Thu Dec 15 22:45:44 2022] POST /api/users/login => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
nginx           | 172.19.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2022:22:45:44 +0000] "POST /api/users/login HTTP/1.1" 500 32 "http://localhost/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Frontend works fine, but as soon as i send any requests for backend I get a status code 500

All solutions I was able to find do not help. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance...

I cannot find any info how to find startup log, so in `app.ini` i added line: `logto = %n.log`, this is output of file `app.log` (only one new)

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.21 (64bit) on [Fri Dec 16 18:47:11 2022] ***
compiled with version: 10.2.1 20210110 on 15 December 2022 21:55:56
os: Linux-5.15.49-linuxkit #1 SMP Tue Sep 13 07:51:46 UTC 2022
nodename: 5338311c006d
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 6
current working directory: /app
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
setgid() to 33
setuid() to 33
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :5555 fd 3
Python version: 3.9.16 (main, Dec  8 2022, 02:40:11)  [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55569cd5a090
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145840 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 7, cores: 1)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 7|app: -1|req: -1/1] 172.19.0.1 () {64 vars in 1239 bytes} [Fri Dec 16 18:47:51 2022] POST /api/users/login => generated 21 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

Comment: It says that the errors are in the startup log, are you able to share that log?

Comment: I added an output of uwsgi log file above ^^ since i couldn't find startup log

Comment: Your `ini` is pointing to `app/main.py`, but from your description of the file system that does not exist. Is that correct?

Comment: The code runs in the docker container. I create volume - volumes:  - ./server:/app , in the description file structure of whole project, inside of container /app is a root folder, and /app/main.py should be same rootOfTheProject/server/main.py. I didn't figure out why it doesn't work, so I just move backend server to Gunicorn instead uWSGI, now testing. On local machine works fine. I hope after deployment it will work as well :)